# Calculating moving average from a table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table in mysql with 4 columns;productId,id, name,count1.
I need to calculate moving average for count1 for 2 rows, based on `id and name.`

```
ProductId   Id  Name    Count1
8           00  XYZ 4
7           00  XYZ 5
6           00  XYZ 9
8           01  XYZ 5
7           01  XYZ 6
6           01  XYZ 7
```

Product id can have multiple Name and Name can have multiple Id. Hence Product id can have same Name multiple times with different Id.
To calculate moving average of count,Id and name should match and ProductId should be in descending order.
And `result` should be

```
Id  Name    Moving_avg(count1)
00  XYZ       4.5
00  XYZ       7
01  XYZ       5.5
01  XYZ       6.5
```

Comment: Would be so easy if MySQL's SQL language would have arrived in the 21st century.

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: logic of moving average, this and next / 2 ?

Comment: @NaveenKumar Name and Id should match and ProductId is considered in descending order

Comment: @NaveenKumar you are right

Comment: Then I still don't get, how your desired result is calculated. (4.5 + 9) / 2 = 6.75

Comment: @fancyPants: No. It should be `( 4 + 5 ) /2` or `( 5 + 9 ) / 2`, etc.

Comment: @fancyPants In first table I have 'XYZ' Name with '00' Id thrice. I need to calculate moving average for 2 rows.Id and name should match. so I have (4+5)/2=4.5 and (5+9)/2=7. This is what I have in first 2 rows of the second table.